# Allow touches to pass through ListView?

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

I'm creating a game and have been trying to achieve this but I cannot. I would like touch events to pass through a ListView and touch what is behind the ListView.

I have been trying to tinker with "filterTouchesWhenObscured" and combining that with "FlagNoTouchModal". I read what there was on Android Developer website but honestly the filtering touches and trying to pass them through a View object is really confusing me.

Can anybody provide any kind of help on this, I have run out of ideas completely on this.

I did notice once, on accident, that if I put an empty Frame Layout, setClickable to FALSE, in an Activity and then touch where it is, the touch events pass through and ignore the Frame Layout.

But I have problems once I put the ListView inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to put invisible surface on listview where you will handle clicks. When you put two views into FrameLayout, which are as big as FrameLayout, the second one would cover the first one.

Comment: I am going to try this out, but for now, Thank You...you helped me see things in a different way. Very thought-provoking...much respect

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know, if this solved your problem.